# How can I use an index from a dataset without mergin all datasets?

Tags: pandas

My datasets:

df1:

| Country | Year | Dem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | 1993 | 152 |
| Spain | 1993 | 223 |
| Spain | 1994 | 166 |
| USA | 1993 | 123 |

df2 (it has many more columns but I only want to use "Index":

| Country | Year | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | 1993 | 0 |
| Spain | 1993 | 1 |
| Spain | 1994 | 1 |
| USA | 1993 | 1 |

Comment: Looks like the two dataframes are the same, no ?

Comment: Now I edited it. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) as shown below :

```
df1.merge(df2[['Country', 'Year', 'Index']], on=['Country', 'Year'], how='left')
```